# How to merge elements of array of arrays in Julia

Tags: julia

I couldn't find a way to do the following in Julia:

Input: `x= [["1","2","3"],["4","5","6"],["7","8","9"]]`

Desired output: `["1 4 7", "2 5 8","3 6 9"]`

Basically, I want to generate n strings where n is the length of x array and each of these strings takes their characters as shown above.

Is there any way to do that ?

**EDIT**

After some thinking I got the following solution but I don't think it is the ideal one. So I still be happy if I get some answer

```
x= [["1","2","3"],["4","5","6"],["7","8","9"]]
y= hcat(x...)
foo(y) = mapreduce(x->string(x," "),string,y)
mapslices(foo,y,2)
```

Comment: you could use a list comprehension as well: `[join([y[place] for y in x], " ") for place in 1:length(x)]`

Comment: I guess this is a better solution. Thanks.

Comment: If one of the answers has solved your question then you should mark it as accepted :)

Comment: @AlexanderMorley yeap you're right. Done :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one way:

```julia
julia> x= [["1","2","3"],["4","5","6"],["7","8","9"]]
3-element Array{Array{String,1},1}:
 String["1","2","3"]
 String["4","5","6"]
 String["7","8","9"]

julia> [join(k, " ") for k in zip(x...)]
3-element Array{String,1}:
 "1 4 7"
 "2 5 8"
 "3 6 9"

julia>
```

Comment: could you explanin the functionality of zip ? I read it from the doc but it doesn't help me to get the idea clearly.

Comment: Looking at the [documentation for zip](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/collections/#Base.zip), in addition to what is shown there, in your own REPL have a look at `collect(c)`.  That may make it's functionality clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I do like rick's one-liner, but I have to say, I'm not sure why you were looking for a 'smart' way of doing it. For loops are very efficient in julia, and this is a simple nested for loop:

```julia
julia> StrList = Array{String, 1}()  # initialise an empty String Array
0-element Array{String,1}

julia> rows = length(x);

julia> for col in 1:length(x[1])
         s = "";                   # empty placeholder string
         for row in 1:(rows-1); 
           s *= x[row][col] * " "; # add N-1 elements with space
         end
         s *= x[rows][col];        # add Nth element without space
         push!(StrList, s); 
       end

julia> StrList
3-element Array{String,1}:
 "1 4 7"
 "2 5 8"
 "3 6 9"
```